# Trouble calling local package into main

Tags: go

I feel like this is probably an over-asked question on SO yet here it is again. I'm finding this simple task incredibly tedious in Go. Note that I have GO11MODULES set to ON, I'm not sure if this effects the whole package system (it shouldn't is what I'm assuming).

I have a package called "users" which contains a compiled Protocol Buffer (from a .proto file). I want to store it alongside a number of other definitions in a folder called `protos`. So that my structure looks like so:

```
- main.go
- protos
   - users.go
   - users.proto
   - analytics.go
   - analytics.proto
```

Pretty simple structure. Within the users.go file I'm defining `package protos`. Within main.go I'd like to `import users "protos/users"`. When I do so I get this: `build command-line-arguments: cannot load protos/users: cannot find module providing package protos/users`.

I've followed (I think) other sample code that has done the same thing. Note that the folder structure is within `$GOPATH/src/myapi`.

Why is this more complicated than its proving to be?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: My GOPATH is /Users/ddibiase/go and my project is at /Users/ddibiase/go/src/myapi. The error is above in the original question (hasn't changed).

Comment: I have GO111MODULE, PATH and GOPATH all set. I don't have a go.mod file anywhere that I know of. Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `package protos`, then the package is `protos`. `protos/users` does not exist. Packages and package imports are directory-level, not file-level. The full import statement depends on the `module` declaration in your go.mod file, which defines the root of imports. E.g., if your go.mod begins with

```
module github.com/me/myapp
```

Then your import would be

```
import "github.com/me/myapp/protos"
```

Comment: THIS was the correct answer. After GO111MODULE is enabled it seems the regular package doesn't reference correctly until you add a go.mod. I followed the above instruction and added module myapi into go.mod and everything resolved as expected. This is incredibly annoying and one of the most painful parts of getting going with Go. BAH!

Comment: You are not, at present, obliged to use modules. You could just put your project under `$GOPATH/src` and reference it according to its path therein.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that GO111MODULE is set to on. The question shows that you are setting GO11MODULES.  I assume that this is a typo.  Fix it if it's not a typoo.

Add file go.mod in same directory as main.go with the following contents:

```
module myapi
```

Change main to import `"myapi/protos"` instead of `"protos/users"`